# Converting wchar_t to wstring

Tags: c++

I always convert `wchar_t*` to `wstring` with `std::wstring x(y)`

But it is not working in this code:

```cpp
        wchar_t f = ctoupper(*cp);
        std::wstring cc(f);
```

`cp` is a `wchar_t*`

Error in the `std::wstring cc(f)` line:

```
E0289   no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>]" matches the argument list
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: do you realize you're just getting the first char, not the whole string?

Comment: `basic_string` (template underneath `string` and `wstring`) is obnoxious for its large number of member functions. Still, it's worth taking a look at them to get an overview. Check out `cppreference.com` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **[`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)** constructor for a single `wchar_t` value. You can achieve your intent with the following:

```
    std::wstring cc(1,f);
```

You can also directly construct a `wstring` out of a c-style null-terminated `wchar_t` array:

```
    std::wstring cc(1,f);   // wstring made with a wchar_t f repeated 1 time
    std::wstring cg(cp);    // wstring made with a wchart_t null terminated array
    std::wcout<<cc<<std::endl<<cg<<std::endl;
```

By the way, you can convert the full wstring to upper with:

```
    for (auto&x:cg) x=towupper(x);
```

([Online demo](https://ideone.com/TTwbg3))

Alternatively you may prefer `toupper(x,std::locale())` toa take into account conversion rules for non ascii characters in your current locale.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to convert a wstring to uppercase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+convert+a+wstring+to+uppercase -- please keep questions to a single topic. Asking for clarification is fine, but don't ask an independent question as add-on to an existing one.

Comment: @Frank I edited my answer with more explanations

Comment: Thank you Christophe will help a lot! :)